# WPF CommandParameter value is changing to null on execution

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I am studying C# WPF and at the moment I am facing an issue.

---

### The app:

I am playing around with the MVVM pattern.
I have built a simple application that includes just
-a ListView that displays a simple collection of a UserControl,
-a Button that adds new items to the ListView and
-a ContextMenu that should allow the user to edit the SelectedItem.

---

### The problem:

I have a SelectedItem property in my ViewModel that is passed down as the CommandParameter to one of my Commands. More specifically, the CmdItemBeginEdit which should allow the user to edit the text inside of the ListView.SelectedItem UserControl.
I have bound my property to the ListView.SelectedItem in TwoWay mode and I have also bound the property as the CommandParameter in the corresponding control.
The thing is that while the SelectedItem is set correctly while selecting a ListView item, when the time comes for the Command to be executed it turns to null.
Why is it happening?

---

### Update #1

I have found some information relevant to my problem. It has to do with the execution order of the Command or something like that and it seems it is a .NET Framework bug (damn you Microsoft).
Other members recommend to define CommandParameter before Command in XAML and also enable Command's IsAsync property to true to begin with. I tried both, but they did not work.
Have you heard anything similar?

---

### The code:

Please note that many techniques and prerequisites have been implemented like ICommand (Command & CommandParameter), INotifyPropertyChanged on Models and ViewModels, ObservableCollection, Binding etc.

My projects includes:
-**MainWindow.xaml** (View)

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Demo.Views.UserControls"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Demo"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<!--To apply to Window level-->
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainVM />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <!--For referencing-->
    <vm:MainVM x:Key="VM" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="btnAddItem"
            Content="Add"
            Width="150"
            Command="{Binding ItemNew}" />
    <ListView x:Name="lviewColelction"
              Width="150"
              MinHeight="100"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <uc:Item DataSource="{Binding}" />

                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Rename"
                                      Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}, Path=ItemBeginEdit}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

-**MainVM.cs** (ViewModel)

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Demo.ViewModels
{
    public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
        {
            var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
        }
        #endregion

        //Properties 
        public ObservableCollection<Models.CustomItem> Items { get; set; }

        private Models.CustomItem selectedItem;
        public Models.CustomItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                    return;
                if (value == selectedItem)
                    return;

                selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Commands.CmdItemNew ItemNew { get; set; }
        public Commands.CmdItemBeginEdit ItemBeginEdit { get; set; }
        public Commands.CmdItemEndEdit ItemEndEdit { get; set; }

        //Constructors 
        public MainVM()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Models.CustomItem>();
            SelectedItem = null;
            ItemNew = new Commands.CmdItemNew(this);
            ItemBeginEdit = new Commands.CmdItemBeginEdit(this);
            ItemEndEdit = new Commands.CmdItemEndEdit(this);

            ReadItems();
        }

        //Methods
        public void SetupItems()
        {
            //Just create demo items. Not used. 
            var items = DatabaseHelper.ReadItems();
            int itemsToCreate = 3 - items.Length;
            while (itemsToCreate > 0)
            {
                CreateItem();
                itemsToCreate--;
            }
        }

        public void CreateItem()
        {
            var item = new Models.CustomItem()
            {
                Name = "New Item"
            };
            DatabaseHelper.Insert(item);
        }

        public void ReadItems()
        {
            var items = DatabaseHelper.ReadItems();
            Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in items)
                Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

---

-**CustomItem.cs** (Model)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using SQLite;

namespace Demo.Models
{
    public class CustomItem
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName);
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //Properties 
        private int id;
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                if (value != id)
                {
                    id = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != name)
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool isEditing;
        [Ignore]
        public bool IsEditing
        {
            get
            {
                return isEditing;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != isEditing)
                {
                    isEditing = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

-**CmdItemBeginEdit.cs** (ICommand)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Demo.ViewModels.Commands
{
    public class CmdItemBeginEdit : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand implementation 
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            var item = parameter as Models.CustomItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            item.IsEditing = true;
        }
        #endregion

        //Properties
        public MainVM VM { get; set; }

        //Constructors 
        public CmdItemBeginEdit(MainVM VM)
        {
            this.VM = VM;
        }
    }
}
```

---

-**CmdItemNew.cs** (ICommand)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Demo.ViewModels.Commands
{
    /// <summary>
    /// We are going to assign a Command for each Button. 
    /// </summary>
    public class CmdItemNew : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand implementation 
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            VM.CreateItem();
            VM.ReadItems();
        }
        #endregion

        //Properties 
        public MainVM VM { get; set; }

        //Constructor 
        public CmdItemNew(MainVM VM)
        {
            this.VM = VM;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show where CmdItemBeginEdit is being used, and also in your xaml you never show the class that defines ItemNew.  I think those are important to helping you resolve this issue.

Comment: The CmdItemBeginEdit is bound in the xaml. The MenuItem Command uses it. 
The CmdItemNew is irrelevant. It is just another Command. I have added it just now though. You may see it as well.

Comment: You probably lose focus when clicking on your command UI element. Then the selection becomes null?

Comment: @Peregrine Let me test it.

Comment: @l33t Losing focus does not change the value of the SelectedItem. I am not sure if it changed the ListView selection, but I do have a separate property in my ViewModel that is being updated through Binding and it does not allow null values in its setter.

Comment: The main issue is that you have two different instances of MainVM - you only require one. Bind to the command using the RelativeSource construct. Also, you don't need to bind the command parameter as MainVM already knows what the selected item is.

Comment: Look at how to use CollectionView and CollectionViewSource. It's a better approach (for me) to track selected item

Comment: @Peregrine I get it. I get what you wrote. I created one instance of VM in Window.DataContext and one instance in the Window.Resources. I have to use one of them. Either one is good. I just have to test it now. Give me some time to  read about RelativeSource and Ancestor properties, so I know what I am doing when looking to grab the reference of my Window.DataContext. Right?

Comment: @Peregrine Thank you! That was the problem. I had two references of ViewModel. One in Window.DataContext and one in Window.Resources. I removed the latter and bound the ContextMenu to my Window.DataContext (top DataContext). 
I had three options to choose from:  
The first one was `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext}`. 
The second one, which was the one that worked, was `{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=windowMain}, Path=DataContext}`. 
The third one was `{Binding ElementName=windowMain, Path=DataContext}`.